# Angularjs don't load controller if press back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am new to AngularJS.

I have 2 views, first one is for customer and other for city. The customer view has some basic fields to add information about customer, including button to add new city.

If I press the "add new city" button, then the view for adding new city is rendered. After this, when I go back on customer view, all previous entered information is lost.

How to keep this information?

Comment: Make use of `service` variables and not `$scope` variables if you want your `ng-models` to retain their values even after navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit a view, angular instantiates the controller again, so if you want the data to be persistence in the app, you should make use of a service, and store the data there.
So when the controller is being instantiated, the controller would load the data from the service.

Comment: Abimbola Idowu:- u r right.. i understand thisconcept when going through problem... still i am not able to find proper solution.. i think i have to work on something like $route events

Comment: I do not really understand what you saying and why you said you want to use $route events, can you reproduce the problem on plnkr and would help you look through it

Comment: :- you are right buddy..... now i got the solution... you are right i keep my data inside service so it will work for me... now my data is persist... thanx buddy

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-show to show the city view rather and hide it using ng-hide once city is added.

If you are looking for state maintenance, implement [$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are pressing back button between pages which has a same parent controller. Add different controller for pages will solve your issue.

Comment: yes u r right using different controller solved my problem but my requirement is to use 1 controller between multiple views

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this after the form with the customer information. Evertyhing is done in the same template and same controller, so no route switching.

Note that the `city` model is updated immediately when you typ the field. If you do not want this, you could implement a `saveCity` method on the scope which write the city model into another model and call it via `ng-click="saveCity()`.

```
<div ng-hide="citySaved">    
  <input type="text" ng-model="city" />
  <button type="button" ng-click="citySaved = true">Save city</button>
</div>
```